# Adding Time and Date to Paper_Trail data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

New to Rails, but learning a ton.

I'm using Paper Trail to save versions of my database, focusing on one sum that I want to maintain with each update. The sum is called "xoi_qb".

Within my model, I have defined the data I want to save like this:

```
 def get_xoi_qb
    xoi_qb = []
    self.versions.each do |version|
      unless version.reify.nil?
        xoi_qb << version.reify.xoi_qb
      end
    end
    return xoi_qb
  end
```

Within my the html page that I want to display this data, I have this:

```
  <p>Previous XOI</p>
  <table summary="XOI Versions">
    <tr>
      <td><%= @quarterback.versions.map { |version| version.reify.xoi_qb} %></td>
    </tr>
```

This is all working properly.

Alongside the "Previous XOI" data, I want to display the time and date that the "xoi_qb" sum is updated (I'm assuming by using "updated_at", but nothing I've tried is working).

Really appreciate your help.

(Side question: my "XOI" sum is appearing with the brackets (i.e. [745]) on the website...if you can tell me how to get rid of that, it would be awesome.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the date and time of the version is stored in the `created_at` field of the version. Did you try that?

As of your side question: you're basically doing `[745].to_s` in your view code, i.e. casting an array to a string, and it does what you're asking it to do. Your code looks like your intention was to output all the previous versions. For this to work you would rather iterate the array than convert it to a string. Something like:

```
<table>
  <% quarterback.versions.each do |version| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= version.reify.xoi_qb %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

... And with dates:

```
<table>
  <% quarterback.versions.each do |version| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= version.reify.xoi_qb %> dated <%= version.created_at %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Excellent! This worked. The only thing I needed to modify from what you added was the "@" added to "@quarterback". Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad to help. Have fun with Rails!